# Is there any intuition behind separation axioms being in terms of closed sets

Tags: general-topology, intuition

It feels like there should exist some intuition behind this. Additionally, Muckres, our textbook, isn’t big on intuition or motivation which lends credence to the conjecture that there could exists so intuitive explanation.

Comment: Did you mean *Munkres*?

Comment: If you include non-closed sets in the separation axioms, those axioms can fail, even in very nice spaces. For example, suppose your space is the real line (with its usual topology) and the two subsets are $\{0\}$ and the open half-line $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: The intuition behind those axioms comes from examples. We take spaces we work with. We then extract their properties and formalize them as axioms. It is just the way the universe works, that these are useful, and other are not. Therefore such "why" questions are more about philosophy rather than maths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to provide another motivation: To supply enough continuous real functions.

We say a family $\mathscr{F}$ of continuous functions on a space $X$ **separates points from closed sets** iff for every closed $F\subseteq X$ and $x\in X-F$, there exists $f\in\mathscr{F}$ such that $f(x)$ is not in the closure of $f[F]$. Now consider the following theorem:

> If $\{f_i\colon X\to X_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of continuous functions that separates points from closed sets in $X$, then $X$ has the initial topology induced by $\{f_i\}_{i\in I}$. Moreover, if $X$ is $T_1$, then the evaluation map $\epsilon$ from $X$ to the product space $\prod X_i$ defined by
> $$
> \epsilon(x)=(f_i(x))_{i\in I}
> $$
> is an embedding.

This theorem is most interesting when every $f_i$ is a bounded continuous real function. In this case, we can study $X$ as a subspace of a product space of bounded closed intervals (called a **cube**). This technique can be used to prove important results like Urysohn's metrization theorem, the existence of Stone-Čech compactifications, etc.

So we'd be happy if a $T_1$ space $X$ admits a family of bounded continuous real functions that separates points from closed sets (boundedness is no real restriction here). That is, for every closed $F\subseteq X$ and $x\in X-F$, we want a continuous real function such that $f(x)$ has an open neighborhood $(f(x)-r,f(x)+r)$ disjoint from $f[F]$. In fact, it suffices to find continuous $f\colon X\to [0,1]$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f[F]=\{1\}$ (that is, it suffices to show that $X$ is $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$). Indeed, if $(g(x)-r,g(x)+r)$ does not intersect $g[F]$ for some continuous $g\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$, then we may assume $g(x)=0$ and $r=1$ without loss of generality, and define $f\colon X\to[0,1]$ by
$$
f(x)=\min\{|g(x)|,1\}.
$$
Then $f\colon X\to[0,1]$ is a continuous function that maps $x$ and $F$ to $0$ and $1$ respectively (for convenience, we say $f$ separates $x$ from $F$).

However, given arbitrary closed $F\subseteq X$ and $x\in X-F$, it can be quite difficult to find a continuous real function $f$ that separates $x$ from $F$. A necessary condition for such $f$ to exist is that $x$ and $F$ are separated by some disjoint open sets, because $\{f<1/2\}$ and $\{f>1/2\}$ are such open sets. Such a $T_1$ space is said to be $T_3$. Since topologies are defined in terms of open sets, it is often easier than $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$ to check if a space is $T_3$.

Unfortunately, not all $T_3$ spaces are $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$ (the counterexamples, however, are very difficult to construct. See [this post on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17371/regular-spaces-that-are-not-completely-regular)). That's when $T_4$ comes into the picture: By Urysohn's lemma (which is really hard to not appreciate), every $T_4$ space is $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$, and $T_4$ is defined in terms of open sets.

I'd say $T_2$ (which ensures the uniqueness of limits) and $T_4$ are the most important separation axioms. But $T_4$ spaces behave badly in some other ways. Unlike $T_n$ for $n\leq 3\frac{1}{n}$, being $T_4$ is not preserved by taking (non-clsoed) subspaces and products, making it harder to produce new $T_4$ spaces from existing ones. For arbitrary subspaces, there's the $T_5$ axiom (enjoyed by all linearly ordered spaces). For products of even just two normal spaces, as far as I know the study can go quite deeply into set theoretic topology (see [Dowker space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dowker_space)).

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Andreas's example in the comments, the key thing is that if you have two disjoint *closed* sets, then their boundaries are disjoint, since they're contained in the sets themselves. Without closedness, two disjoint sets could share boundary points, in which case there's no hope of separating them.

Comment: But, why do I care abt the “boundaries”. For instance, what if I made separation axioms abt separating open and/or points with closed sets?

Comment: I would conjecture boundaries are important because you can enforce that closure implies containing all subsequences? ie def in motivated by connection between topo and analysis

Comment: @EEH That would fail quite generally as Andreas's example shows. Non-closed sets can have boundary points that are disjoint from it... these will be in the closure of the set so you can't separate them with closed sets.

Comment: @EEH I'm trying to give intuition here... separation axioms are about there being some "space" between sets, but how could there be any space between two sets that share a boundary?

Comment: I don’t follow Andrea’s example. What about the set {0} and (0,$/infty$)? What exactly would fail?

Comment: $\{0\}$ and $(0,\infty)$ can't be separated by open sets (or by any reasonable notion of separation). So if your separation axiom were "singletons and open sets can be separated," that would fail even in the real numbers.

Comment: @EEH And to my point, any reasonable notion *should* fail here, since $0$ is a limit point of $(0,\infty).$

Comment: Saying that it would fail *even* in the real numbers is significant why? (I’m not trying to be difficult and this is helpful).

Comment: On the next point, you are saying it should fail because useful/interesting (or just intuitive ones?) topo’s wouldn’t let you stick a set between an open set and its closure. That would be “weird” basically. (The limit point part seems like what I was guessing at in my second comment “connection between topo and analysis” because sequences don’t seem significant to point set topo from my understanding of it)

Comment: @EEH Because separation axioms are one way of quantifying how much a space is like the real line (or like metric spaces, more generally). Yes, that’s essentially what I’m saying, only I’m not really talking about what topological spaces should do but how a notion of “separation” should behave. So yes, the connection to analysis is important… point set topology is a generalization of the topological spaces that come up in analysis. Sequences are still important but we can’t always use them to the same effect as with the reals/metric spaces (there are generalizations called “nets” and “filters”)

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help. I have physics background. I have experience with smooth manifolds but very little with analysis outside of first course. My classmates have mentioned some of motivation/intuition in Munkres comes from analysis/metric spaces. This seems to be an example of that.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different abstract properties defined in maths, some of them even have a name attached. But not all are equally important. For example we do consider spaces were arbitrary intersection of open subsets is open, a.k.a. [Alexandrov space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology). There's a good chance that you will never hear about it, even if you are a professional mathematician. Why? Because it is not important. Why? Because it doesn't occure in problems or applications. It's just rare for a topological space to be Alexandrov.

The same is with those separation axiom. We consider them, because lots of spaces that we study have some or all of them. That's just how the universe is constructed. We only observe those patterns.

As a physicist you should understand this analogy: why the speed of light is finite? It's a similar question. It just is. That's how the universe works.

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment you outline, but in mathematics, unlike physics, the question of why doesn't xyz show up is a valid question (in this case why don't Alexandrov spaces show up). I do appreciate that this doesn't necessitate an insight-provoking answer to such question, and thus such questions may not always be "good" questions.